# MongoDB 5.0 Replication: Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, replication, mongodb-replica-set

I would like to know how to fix the following error when enabling replication on MongoDB: `<Server address=db-master:27017 UNKNOWN>` It only happens when enabling replication.

**Error**

```
Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable (No nearest server is available in cluster: #<Cluster topology=ReplicaSetNoPrimary[db-master:27017,db-node2:27017,db-node1:27017,name=rs0,v=6,e=7fffffff0000000000000017] 
servers=[#<Server address=db-master:27017 UNKNOWN>,#<Server address=db-node2:27017 UNKNOWN>,#<Server address=db-node1:27017 UNKNOWN>]> with timeout=30, LT=0.015)
```

Is this issue due to DNS resolution? Is there a way to specify the IP address instead of the alias (from hosts file) to the cluster topology?
When `ssh'ing` to the primary and secondary nodes pinging seems to work.

```
[db-node2 server] $ ping db-master
PING db-master ([IP_IS_HERE]) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from db-master ([IP_IS_HERE]): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.153 ms
64 bytes from db-master ([IP_IS_HERE]): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.150 m
```

**mongo.conf**

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0,localhost,127.0.0.1,db-master,[IP_IS_HERE]
  bindIpAll: true
replication:
  replSetName: "rs0"
```

**ubuntu hosts**

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
[IP_IS_HERE] db-master
[IP_IS_HERE] db-node1
[IP_IS_HERE] db-node2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you start the mongod service on the other hosts?

Your config does not make much sense. If you want to permit connection from any host, then use

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIpAll: true
```

or

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

If you want to limit the connection from specific host then use

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: localhost,db-master,[IP_IS_HERE]
```

ssh uses port 22 but your MongoDB uses port 27017, so your firewall may block the connection (the same applies for `ping`). If you like to check whether connection is available you can use `curl` command:

```
curl --connect-timeout 3 --silent --show-error db-node1:27017
```

If you get as response

> It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.

then connection is possible.

An response of

> Connection timed out after 3000 milliseconds

indicates that your firewall blocks the connection attempt.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on bindIpAll and bindIp, It works : )